# Partial encoding loss when angular4 http post passes Base64 encoding back to the background

Tags: angular, http, base64, http-post

I use http post to submit the base64 encoding,but part of the encoding is lost.And i use genymotion to test the function.The base64 code received by the console is as follows.
/Aea8OZVZvj7xayB57xBx472efvXIP9X8iain/q k1a7/ANX8llGXDJ wSfsq/sffHHQ9ZuPgZ4qstH1YW0MqS6Rr2va/b6cfPJzdeGfEV0L7TCQMEMNPG24bA3gOPzc MnwR8d/AnxTJ4d8WWsZt7lxNpGu2y27WGvwKITcahaXMF3eG3tlJwt0flvARg5 2iHzrw34i8UeCvEFl4g8K61faLremTC50/VbC5W0vLY vXB49 D78V 2fhXU9F/bQ/ZjvY9btbSLxlpshstVitWli8rxdpywXNnPpwguQTpOveRb3IXI a 1HcQdGFTryOpBqXVRvva7Ti7tWaS12cprRtzkexwxLw7 lVRzLgnEcC8CeGXjHHIo57wJn/AaeR8A8ef2E2pcP59w/dJSspcmfXzjP5S5 IZNLJ58PZl Gu11GPNwP uYPdvc /wCvPFOBVFJLceuD6sOmCe38 RmnNHNbz3VpdQzQSw3Atp4bj/lhy3r93jPvnoSd1RbfLjXnOzHP1Z cfjz9RwTmvQoO7nqne3RL/n5ukvJd003u1M/iGdKtRrSpVbWtppZ7yTvr5aadXo2myaiiiugAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKAP1B/4JufDnT5H8efF3WLWOSTTJh4P0Se4P/IN/4l51LxLqHOMf8Sz zQMknnXDk4JPxh 0R8bdc OfxH1rXbq9um8M2N7cWPgzShH 403SzAPsmbUDcdU1wj 2fEIJIBbjO4sf0Q/4J4yW r/s9fFHwlb3WzVP Ew1n7R/07f8JH4Q8L6bpmodeQf7M1HA7Z4JJNfkJqOk6noupaho q2slpqOnXk1neQ3Eg 2QXFpGJ7uwypIB6ZB5zw2GBA8f vxtf8Ar776n9e IGYZrk30PPo 5Nk1sryPinP/ABAz7j5Xds z/I I2sifEC5v hHHbZLJZJyvkt3n75MyY4xt Tg/3h1z1 XPXnp3r9G/ Ce/xs1vRPHp CutapNdeHfFdte3PhuGaf8A5AniXTbA6iP7MG7jStd0sahx/wBB8EnByT cyqAGXOQudoAPz43Z59cnv7DPBz9N/sV HtR139pfwCbGKbydGubvxDfTw/8ALrZ6dp q9s87tUTTdHPXP9oDB Uk9ym7P34/ZWkWm7uSV/dbut7X6tKSer/EfAjM8 yDxm8J8w4fT/tP/Xvh/Zv/AJnvETyF5C9ea3ECj/YO7tFXu9Dov21/hinw3 OesX2noiaN4ytrbXdDtFINnaiGxddRgGWZsLd2twq5UIFCrGxwwX7d8QTz D/ CatnJoBEEk/w88GRMYVBAl8W I9NPiDhhg5Oo6jgHIyDkHGa cP CkGtaZffFrwrpFrL515oPhKJNUODm2n1nWtS1K35IK5GlwWh4JYZIKgZM/0t zdJYfHf9iXUfhtLLHNqGh2mp Eru0d8Spf6brJ8SeD4RhsjSzB9k7g5sNZORgk8VC6oVrrS2LVtlyp1ElFNW Gzt15k5NKPvf3Fw1lGSUPpi/Sk4E4Wzl5XmPHPhN4lZBw/G1l/r5nmV5Dnuerl7ZBmSzzPkrpZG8l1TTPxgAwm0qCP97j7zH19SPx7gim7VVXYcDjnk55ZemcjBC 5yeeCat6np2oaJf3enalbSWt/ps1xaXljcDN7bT2m4XlhwSDx1wSQSF4O7NU7QWB 78u4c9idvQ569x6nJPOelbb3Urfm76N79r36NN3uv80a2Fx2X43McBj8AspzHKUrb/zVdk91JWtb4nfRMRkLlgxxj7nvyc9 MALn6DqSa/Ur/gmPfXwvvjBpZE39lz2Xgy Xt5N6NR8T6aenPBAI5/5cepANflkBEocN85GMfeGeWz0JHQjqfXkkmv2c/YA8ET APgv4u J3iRZLJfFt4NQs96GTPhjwlBq1uLm2HP2gk6l4iGfvZIGCF3Nsv3XW8Wmr2tbV6p3e7te l urt/UH0JslzTMPpIcEYnAtpZUs/wA z6W6/sB5BxHkLcneyUs7z7Isht3zmCTS5j8z/wBpWzhsP2gfi1ZWi/6LYeK9VtoUIPA8iPA5OeFwOpHB4ALZ8WVlQN5a5U4xzjoWH8XPXP8A9Yc10/jnxTd OvGXijxhft5Fz4i1u 1aUbR/qnur6T7ygf8AP2Dz8x4DMzBmPMRsAzfN3/enn95ywH0/DqBzkissLFRw9GlU10j3tpzJtWe 1ktG3BWbba/BfEDOcJxBx/4icSZV/wAi7iHjrPc9yBq1nkOe8QcRZ6rOzfLeLb3WsU9Eyeiiiu0 WCiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooA lP2Sfj fgL8RbvUdWM0/g7xVDZaP4st4cf6KMsNM8QYyM/2Hg5Hbw/qGtAliQa/QD45/sheEP2hJR8X/g94q0Sx1DxPEL/VHiJ1bw54vhAKJfaZeafdWlvpmpoBhVBXO47mICV MUQbB2r 7PUcdi/I bJ5GfxYZyCa9J Hnxa KHwslmk8A OdY8PJKPNubDTphPpd0C1zj 09O1I/2TxtyM5yAASMAnl5nqudb6NLVL3kre49dE9/5NrNv hfCXx0yfhbhHMfCrxU4G/4iX4W5rnyz7 wVfIuIMhz 7vxDkGf3td25pcPOOTaWtxDkzjxGsy kdG/YB/aJvda/s7UtL0TSdK88bteuvEOkTKhAkIAttOu9Z1YgtgEnTshSHwW Q/d3gTwH8H/ANhn4a614o8Xa1baj4u1O0ht7/VES5h1TWLjzzBp3h/wtpp 1lNJBmgJxwST4k8Truwp/Ou4/bk/aevLJ7FfiJa2e3/j6nsfCng60vBln24/4lGRnGcDJHGSAOfmjxN4u8W NtWn1/xh4k1rxHqsv/L/AK5e6heXgyX9Tzyff7x4wDnmS J 2d9Fq1/e974ndvra9vdZ lZR42/R28H/AO0OIvAnw34 zTj/AP4Xv7Bz/wAWnw8v9QrOd/7AyDIeIc Sk9OmTZ le3EDSlfb JXxA1b4p PPE/j/AFyV49R8Q3cF9cW0Ugms7WDlbWxBAAI06z/s/SACCVBCl2ZTIfUv2ZP2g9T/AGfvHbaz5d1qfhTXxZWHijRIT/x9WQJ/s3UNNBP/ACFdC2455 YYBNfOyE5UKf8AcG3Hd8/oCR9cckU2NMmQMPm UAH3Jz3x0HHPTHXPPVTtCk3d2WyTd7cyj1395X66N3vJXP5QwXGXFmD4y/4iBheIP MuWfLPln61l/rBf 3Y8QJt3t0cu7i21zcy/av4pfs2fCL9q/SJPil8I/Fej2Ov6isRu9atYrmXRL 4Mzeedd0M3drdeGvFTW3Jt7rlvl/4p61AJr4c1H9gr9pKw1J7TS/Cuma1Yr/q9Rh8R HbWBzhiQYNR8Q2Gr43dD9sztwTgsRXzR4M8eeOvh/qsmqeBvFGt Gb3jz5tJv/ALILnl8f2ppxP/EyGfmHPcAkg19G2f7dv7T9tbRW7 NdLuxDjfdXHhPw8Lzqw4H9k8dh05IbkgMa5KUZOTne2uu1m25aq7sno9E7Xtu0pP8AqTMvGX6N3itUlnPjX4WZ/wAKcf6vPc 8JP8AV1xz58z97P8AIOIOIU H72vaP9scQPX/AIyHmTk/pj4P/wDBPWXTr608RfHDXdPudN06I37 FtMIIaczXAxrviW2u2/s3SVBDB9Oxk4U IcBmbG/bJ/as8Ma14fuPgj8I9TgudE3Wdj4w8Q6JIYdLEOnXDHTPDGhefuN1pT5PQhtxJY/L/pHxT4 /aC N/xRtZNN8b/EDWtU0ucnztLtvsGm6Xdclj/aWl6a iaRqfAPPPBbsM140q4Tae2Mn/nnksRxk53AdOwzkgnNdkIQpp6q7vq 3Nv8TXSz3eq3s4nj8W/SD4MyHg3iDws j1wK CMi4qSXH3EGf2zzj/PrNJR0VuH7WzrSOe507Z3bh1ZNfiS9iiiiug/lMKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooA//Z

Here is my code.
public postList(url,params) {

```
    // console.log(params);

    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{

    this.http.post(url,params)

    .map(res=>res.json())

    .subscribe(data=>{

        resolve(data);

    },err=>{

        reject(err);

        })

    })

}
```

Answer (score 0):

why are you using res.json() stream to encode a base64 value. Res.json is only used when a JSON value comes as the return from API call, just return res instead of res.json()

Comment: The usage of my map is to pass the background parameters passed into json format.And param I pass to the background is of type string.